# Why GridLayoutManager is filling items from bottom to top and from right to left?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I tested my code in **API 24, 26, 27 and 28** and it worked like a charm (**Top to Bottom** and **Left to Right**) but when I tested it in **API 16** I found out that `GridLayoutManager` is filling items from **Bottom to Top** and from **Right to Left**. I guess this problem occurs in **API<17**

This is My Code:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

[image]

How can I fix it in **API 16**?

---

### EDIT:

It is important to know this problem doesn't occur for All Devices < API 17 . because I tested app in Samsung Galaxy S3 (API 16) and it didn't reverse the list.

Comment: Test case try this **`GridLayoutManager  gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 2,GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);`**

Comment: I tested it before asking the question. It doesn't work!

Comment: API 17 was the first to introduce native RTL support, so that's where the issue might be coming from. Is your device or activity configured as RTL?

Comment: @Pawel Thank you for your explanation. None of them are configured as RTL. is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I decided to reverse my ArrayList when the API level of an Android device is lower than 17 (4.2 or **JELLY_BEAN_MR1**).

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    Collections.reverse(mlist);
}
```

and then it is obvious that I should set mList to recyclerAdapter.